# json boolean vs integer - which takes up less space?

Tags: json

When sending a value in JSON otw, is it better to use a boolean or an integer to use up less space?

e.g:

```
{
  foo: false
}
```

Or:

```
{
  foo: 0
}
```

Would using a number use less space, considering its just a number, compared to 4 or 5 characters for a boolean value? (true/false)

Also is there a speed difference between the two approaches if you convert them from JSON to object format?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, this is *micro-optimisation*, and *very unlikely to be important*. If you are transporting thousands or millions of such values, it might become significant; but in that case, you probably want something much more efficient than JSON anyway (a plain CSV would be better in many cases, but ideally you'd use some packed binary format).

Secondly, JSON is a way of representing data in a string; so storing or sending JSON means you are storing or sending strings. Measuring the size of the data is therefore trivial: how long is the string? The string `0` has one character; the string `false` has five characters.

Thirdly, if you're optimising for space, you'd remove all insignificant whitespace, so your examples should be `{"foo":false}` (13 characters) and `{"foo":0}` (9 characters). Note that you *can't*, as you have in your example, skip the quote marks around `foo` - that is not valid JSON.

Fourthly, how much memory or other resources the structure will take up when you convert it from JSON into an object depends on what language you're using, what implementation of that language, and any number of other factors, so is completely unanswerable (and, again, a micro-optimisation that is very unlikely to be important).

Answer (score 0):

I think integer is a better solution because, besides using less space (and consequentially, being potentially faster to parse), it is also more future proof. Someone can easily convert it into a three (or more) state variable if needed by just assigning other values like -1, 2, 3..., while the conversion from boolean would be less straight forward.